# Resharper custom patterns find/copy comments

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I want to get description from

```
[Test(Description = "My description")]
```

and create comment

```
/// <summary>
/// My description
/// </summary>
[Test(Description = "My description")]
```

How to define a custom patterns in ReSharper?

Comment: Rly? Duplicate the description text, just to fulfill some "all (public) methods must have a doc comment" policy? Maybe exclude test methods from this policy?